# How to show short string inside tab-content of vue-form-wizard but display full string inside component's prop

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-form-wizard

I want to display short text inside ***tab-content*** of [vue-form-wizard](https://binarcode.github.io/vue-form-wizard) but display full text inside component's prop.

***tab-content*** should display countries abbreviation, e.g. USA, UK, UAE etc. whereas the component should take full name as prop.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <form-wizard>
    <tab-content
      v-for="country in countries"
      :key="country.id"
      :title="country.title"
    >
      <component
        :is="country.name"
        :title="country.title"
      />
    </tab-content>
  </form-wizard>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      countries: [
        {
          id: 0,
          title: 'United States',
          name: 'UnitedStates',
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'United Kingdom',
          name: 'UnitedKingdom',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'United Arab Emirates',
          name: 'UnitedArabEmirates',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to put the short names inside the step circle?

Comment: Yes, inside the step circle.

Comment: Then you will need to rewrite or replace the [WizardStep.vue](https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard/blob/master/src/components/WizardStep.vue) component.

Comment: As idea, you could put small country flag icons instead of short names. Something like this https://semantic-ui.com/elements/flag.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a variant with the short names.

```
<div id="app">
<form-wizard>
    <tab-content
      v-for="country in countries"
      :key="country.id"  
      :title="shortName(country)"
    >
      {{country.title}}
    </tab-content>
  </form-wizard>
</div>
```

using:

```
 countries: [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'United States',
      name: 'UnitedStates',
      short: 'US'
    },
```

and

```
methods: {      
    shortName(country) {
        return country.short
    }
  }
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/am807eud/)

There is no slot inside the step to provide a custom content. You can only provide a icon instead of the step number. Like in this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s96dhg4f/)

Comment: Is there any way to change the title from within tab-content data binding? :title="country.title" instead :title="convertToShort(country.title)". So I don't have to add one more property in the countries array. Because countries data is coming from the back-end without short title.

Comment: Sure, you can put any valid js into the :title="", so you can use a function to do this.

Comment: I have updated the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/am807eud/